# How to get classLoader of netbeans specify project

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I develop a simple plugin for netbeans platform. I wonder how can i get a classpath of specify java project (for example i have opened two WebJavaProject) and now i dont know how can i get a classsLoader for specify project.

Im trying something like but this dosent work:

```
      FileObject f = this.project.getProjectDirectory();
      ClassPath cpCompile = ClassPath.getClassPath(f, ClassPath.COMPILE);
      cpCompile.getClassLoader(true);
```

can any body know how can i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for a more specific classpath. One project will usually contain classpath for sources and classpath for tests. If you start from a project you probably want to access its `Sources` or `SourceGroups` (check `ProjectUtils.getSources(org.netbeans.api.project.Project)` and `JavaProjectConstants.SOURCES_TYPE_JAVA`). This will give you source roots and there will be classpath associated with them.